# Combining multiple for loops into CSV with selenium

Tags: python, list, csv, selenium, xpath

So, I'm trying to figure out how to scrape a directory site for some information and I'm having trouble combining two sets of get_elements into a writable CSV file. I have two lists of information `company_links_elements` and `company_address_elements`. Ultimately what I'd like to do is print the following information to a CSV. The problem is I don't know how to run two `for loops` together or `zip the arrays`. Can you help me figure out how to get a CSV with the following three rows: `company_name`, `company_url`, and `company_address`.

```
company_links_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='jss320 
jss324 jss337 sc-gzOgki eucExu']/a")
company_address_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//strong[@class='dtm-search-listing-address']")

with open('links.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for company in company_links_elements:
        company_url = company.get_attribute("href")
        company_name = company.get_attribute("text")
        # NEED COMPANY ADDRESS HERE
        writer.writerow((company_name, company_url))

driver.close()
```

Notice the company_address_elements... I don't know how to include that into the csv.writer to write the additional column for the company_address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for idx, company in enumerate(company_links_elements):
        company_url = company.get_attribute("href")
        company_name = company.get_attribute("text")
        address = company_address_elements[idx].get_attribute(...)
        writer.writerow((company_name, company_url))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [zip version](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for company, address in zip(company_links_elements, company_address_elements):
    company_url = company.get_attribute("href")
    company_name = company.get_attribute("text")
    company_address = address. get_attribute("text")
```

On every iteration `company` and `address` will be the corresponding element in the lists, at the same index. Will stop when the shorter list is exhausted. Benefit over enumerate - you won't hit IndexError if one of the list is shorter than the other; negative - you don't have the current index at hand (but you don't use it anyways:).